# How do I call a Web Service inside a DLL

Tags: c#, web, dll, service

I can't find references to add the link in the DLL. How do I do it?
I tried to do it manually but it can only load file.

UPDATE:
I found it, I added the DLL to my form. I have to read all the information that the user writes in the form and send the date to a document using my function in the DLL. Here's what I have:
[DLL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb2Pe.png)

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03eTY.png)

How do I call my function from my DLL

Comment: The question is unclear and lacks enough detail for anyone to help. What exact steps are you taking and what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Did you write the DLL yourself? Have you tried any solution, please post it here. A DLL is just the output of a library project. You would normally call it from a main program, which is in another project. Opening a link from a DLL is not different from doing this from your main program. I recommend you start with a simple console application, open the link and do something. Once you got this working, create the class library in  separate project and open the link from there, though in general you may provide the actual link from your main program.

Comment: @RudolfJan Basically I have to add a date to some files that the user chooses and I have to call the Web Service in a void function that sends the date to the web service inside the DLL. I searched all over the internet and I can't seem to find how to do it.

Comment: I have to read a username, a password, a url and the date pass it to the DLL and pass it to Web Service

Comment: For me, you still have lot of trouble to explain what your issue is. If you post code, please create a simple example and post the code not screenshots and make sure other people can run this code, or at leats most of it.

Comment: I undertsand you created a Winform application, which calls a class library. If you want to use webservices, make sure your class library is a ASP.Net library.  You have them in a number of variants, you will know which one to use once you did an ASP.Net tutorial, but a API would be fine probably. This should allow you to start communicatiing with the webservice. Then your asp.net code may have a method you call from the UI to invoke the API and send your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot will definitely try it @RudolfJan